# How to make timelike entanglement in the laboratory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, quantum-entanglement

http://io9.com/5744143/particles-can-be-quantum-entangled-through-time-as-well-as-space

http://arxiv.org/abs/1101.2565

1. How to make timelike entanglement in the laboratory?
2. How to test whether mixed state exist in time series or control system in math?