# What is Time Entanglement?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, time, quantum-entanglement

According to (https://www.quantamagazine.org/time-entanglement-raises-quantum-mysteries-20160119) Time Entanglement is different than regular entanglement (spacial) we have. Would you please explain what time entanglement is and how does it work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entanglement in time](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/27641/)

Comment: See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3579/25301, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/44731/25301 (unanswered) and https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/3357/25301